# How to read or get the request payload headers in the browser using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I managed to write a ruby script which uses capybara `(Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies)` to read the cookie from a browser. I could not find methods to read the complete request headers of a API. Like Method, Content-Type, Accept-language, CSRF etc.

Can someone shed some lights please!

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; You shouldn't be using Capybara to write API tests

You're using the wrong tool for the job. Capybara is designed to test an application from the users perspective. Since a user doesn't really care about things like headers (just the affect they have in the browser) Capybara doesn't provide them. It's also why you had to go so far down in driver specific methods to get cookies - you really shouldn't be directly accessing those in Capybara driven tests either, just testing the behaviors the cookies control happen.